# Reverting animation done with AnimatorSet

Tags: android, android-animation

I am creating an animation with `AnimatorSet` and when it ends I would like to leave the `View` where it was.

The code is something like this:

```
mLastAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
mLastAnimation.playTogether(
  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "scaleX", 1.5f, 1f),
  ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "translationY", 40f, 0f));
mLastAnimation.setDuration(3000);
mLastAnimation.addListener(this);
mLastAnimation.start();

// The Activity implements the AnimatorListener interface
  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
    // Undo the animation changes to the view.
  }
```

EDIT:

I am using the new animation API so `setFillAfter()` will not work here.

Comment: do you want to animate it in reverse?

Comment: @userSeven7s: Nope, just placing the `View` to the original position after the animation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the properties of the `View` back to its original values.

For example if you translateY 40 pixels forward, you need to translateY 40 pixels backwards. This is because the actual *properties* of the `View` have changed during **property animation**, not just the way it is rendered.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#property-vs-view

Comment: I know that but I want to avoid setting everything in place after doing animations. Imagine a more complex `AnimatorSet`, with more `ObjectAnimator`s. Setting everything back to place is quite a pain. I am hoping to find a way to read stuff inside the `AnimationSet` and reverting them.

Comment: Then try view animation instead of property animation. As far as I'm aware, there is no other way to revert the changes.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a snapshot of the `View`'s state and set the absolute values afterwards.

Comment: Since I am using nineOldDroids for older platforms I am not sure if I can create a snapshot of the `View`'s state. I will check it out.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using nineoldandroids there is a function called `reverse`. You can set the duration to be 0 and call `reverse` to reverse the animation.

Answer (score 4):

While using `ObjectAnimator` you can simply set

```
android:repeatMode="reverse"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "scaleX", 1.5f, 1f);
// here is the important part!
scaleX.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
scaleX.setRepeatCount(1);
ObjectAnimator transl = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "translationY", 40f, 0f));
// here is the important part!
transl.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
transl.setRepeatCount(1);

mLastAnimation = new AnimatorSet();
mLastAnimation.playTogether(scaleX, transl);
// the rest is the same...
```